# How can I return a class from an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Is it possible to return a class from an async method? I get an error message that there is an `GetAwaiter` missing? Don't know what this means.

```
StatusButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            ...             
            byte[] TheResponse = new byte[1024];
            await TheResponse = client.Read(); // <---- GetAwaiter ?
        };          

public class Client
{
    ...

    public async Task<byte[]> Read()
    {
        var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] Result = new byte[1024];
        await ns.ReadAsync(Result, 0, Result.Length);
        return Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is that…?

Comment: You're almost certainly doing something wrong if you're not checking the return value from [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx). It *may* return as little as a single byte.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to return a class from an async method?

Yes.

> I get an error message that there is an GetAwaiter missing, what does that mean?

It means that the variable namely `TheResponse` was declare as a `byte[]`, however you're attempting to assign it as a `Task<byte[]>`. The IDE however, has a preemptive check on the use of the `async` keyword and complains to you about the type you're attempting to await doesn't have the `GetAwaiter` method. This is because it is a `byte[]`. Here is an example [<kbd>`.NET fiddle`</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LZbzG) demonstrating this issue.

There are lots of little things that I want to call attention to here. First, when your return type is `Task`, `Task<T>` or any other asynchronous return type - it is best practice to name the method with the "Async" suffix, i.e.; `ReadAsync`. Furthermore, it wouldn't hurt to be more explicit than that. Since you're only able to return a `Task<byte[]>` from this method, let's call it `ReadBytesAsync`, yeah?

Ok, so now that we have a clearly defined client and corresponding API let us look at its usage. When you use the `async` keyword that enables the usage of the corresponding `await` keyword. These two keywords work together and can never be used alone.

Think of the `Task<byte[]>` as a promise that after sometime I'll give you a `byte[]`, but you must "await" this. In your code, you're placing the `await` in the wrong location. Instead you should have the following:

```
StatusButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        ...

        byte[] bytes = await client.ReadBytesAsync();
    };
```

There is no reason to declare and initialize the variable only to attempt to reassign it, as you had done. Instead simple declare and initialize the value from the awaited response of the invocation to the `.ReadBytesAsync` call. Note, that without the `await` keyword you'd have the `Task<byte[]>` that represents the asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, now it runs. Had to made some changes. Here they are: Maybe someone can use it.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...

        OpenButton.Click += delegate
        {
            SendCommand('O');
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ShutDown());
        };

        ...
    }


    async void SendCommand(Char Command)
    {
        ... //Command not used in this part of code

        const string sn = "SEND_NONCE";

        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sn);

        Client client = new Client();

        TcpClientPacket TheData = new TcpClientPacket(sn.Length);

        TheData.Buffer = data;
        TheData.Length = sn.Length;

        bool IsConnected = await client.InitializeAsync(HostUrl, Port);

        ...

        await client.WriteAsync(TheData);

        TcpClientPacket TheResponse = await client.ReadAsync(16);

        ...

    }


    public class Client
    {
        private TcpClient tcpClient;

        public async Task <bool> InitializeAsync(string ip, int port)
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return tcpClient.Connected;
        }

        public void Deactivate()
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

        public async Task WriteAsync(TcpClientPacket Data)
        {
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            await ns.WriteAsync(Data.Buffer, 0, Data.Length);
        }

        public async Task<TcpClientPacket> ReadAsync(int ExpectedLength)
        {
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            TcpClientPacket Result = new TcpClientPacket(ExpectedLength);
            Result.Length = await ns.ReadAsync(Result.Buffer, 0, ExpectedLength);
            return Result;
        }

    }

    public class TcpClientPacket
    {
        public byte[] Buffer;
        public int Length;

        public TcpClientPacket(int Size)
        {
            Buffer = new byte[Size];
            Length = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StatusButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    ...
    byte[] TheResponse = new byte[1024];
    TheResponse = await client.Read();          // <---- place await in the correct place
};
```